# NLTK SklearnClassifier wrapper data

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I was trying to to make a `sklearn` classifier within the `nltk.SklearnClassifier` wrapper and came across this question that if we don't train the classifier at once (which all of the tutorials out there do) and train it one data at a time, will it delete destroy the previous training done to the classifier . I hope I made myself clear but if not here is some code to explain.

```
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

class classifier(object):
    def __init__(self,c):
        self.c = c

    def train(self,featuresets):
        self.c.train(featuresets)

    def classify(self,feature):
        self.c.classify(feature)

clf = classifier(SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB()))
while True:
    #some lengthy operation
    clf.train(featuresets)
    #some lengthy operation again
    clf.classify(feature)
```

I hope you now understood what I am trying to say. So when the `clf` gets trained  in the loop then does all the previous training gets useless or not and if it does get useless what are the other ways to achieve the same? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything depends on classifier you're using. Not all sci-kit classifiers are able to learn multiple times.

If you want to train it multiple times set warm_start = True when initializing your classifier object.

MultinomialNB doesn't have possibility to be trained multiple times. i.e. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html is able to do this.

Nevertheless firstly it's good to think whether you really need to train it multiple times. Incremental learning is used usually when your data overcaps your viable memory.

```
warm_start : bool, default: False

When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit as initialization,
otherwise, just erase the previous solution. Useless for liblinear solver.
```